# ATA disk driver "skipping" chunk of memory

Tags: c++, x86, operating-system, disk

I'm trying to write a simple 32 bit x86 operating system and I have an issue with my ATA disk driver code.

I have written the following C++ class whose function `read_sects_pio28` should read `sect_count` disc sectors, starting at offset `sect_offs`, to physical address `pa_dest`:

```
template<typename T>
void out(uint16_t port, T data)
{
  asm ("out %0,%1"
       : : "a" (data), "d" (port));
}

template<typename T>
T in(uint16_t port)
{
  T data;
  asm volatile("in %1,%0"
               : "=a" (data)
               : "d" (port));
  return data;
}

template<typename T>
void ins(uint16_t port, uint32_t dest, uint32_t count)
{
  static_assert(detail::is_uint_le32_t<T>());

  asm volatile("rep ins%z2"
               : "+D" (dest), "+c" (count), "=m" (dest)
               : "d" (port)
               : "memory");
}

class Disk_driver_ata
{
  enum : uint32_t
  {
    ATA_PORT_DATA = 0x1F0,
    ATA_PORT_SECT_COUNT = 0x1F2,
    ATA_PORT_LBA_LO = 0x1F3,
    ATA_PORT_LBA_MID = 0x1F4,
    ATA_PORT_LBA_HI = 0x1F5,
    ATA_PORT_DRIVE_HEAD = 0x1F6,
    ATA_PORT_STATUS = 0x1F7,
    ATA_PORT_CMD = 0x1F7
  };

  enum : uint8_t
  {
    ATA_PIO48_MASTER = 0x40,
    ATA_PIO48_CMD_READ = 0x24,
    ATA_STATUS_DRQ = 0x08
  };

public:
  void read_sects(uint32_t pa_dest,
                  uint64_t sect_offs,
                  uint16_t sect_count) const override
  { read_sects_pio48(pa_dest, sect_offs, sect_count); }

private:
  static void read_sects_pio48(uint32_t pa_dest,
                               uint64_t sect_offs,
                               uint16_t sect_count)
  {
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_DRIVE_HEAD, ATA_PIO48_MASTER);

    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_SECT_COUNT, (sect_count >> 8) & 0xFF);
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_LBA_LO, (sect_offs >> 24) & 0xFF);
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_LBA_MID, (sect_offs >> 32) & 0xFF);
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_LBA_HI, (sect_offs >> 40) & 0xFF);
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_SECT_COUNT, sect_count & 0xFF);
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_LBA_LO, sect_offs & 0xFF);
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_LBA_MID, (sect_offs >> 8) & 0xFF);
    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_LBA_HI, (sect_offs >> 16) & 0xFF);

    x86::outb(ATA_PORT_CMD, ATA_PIO48_CMD_READ);

    for (uint8_t sec = 0u; sec < sect_count; ++sec) {
      poll_status(ATA_STATUS_DRQ);

      x86::ins<uint32_t>(ATA_PORT_DATA, pa_dest, DISK_SECT_SIZE / 4);
      pa_dest += DISK_SECT_SIZE / 4;
    }
  }

  static void poll_status(uint8_t status)
  {
    while (!(x86::in<uint8_t>(ATA_PORT_STATUS) & status))
      ;
  }
};
```

I want to use this this function to load the executable ELF segment of my kernel, which is currently only 688 bytes large, to address `0x100000`. On disk, the segment starts at `0x1800` and so `read_sects_pio28` is called with `pa_dest=0x10000`, `sect_offs=12`, `sect_count=2` (I have verified that this is actually the case using a debugger).

But this seems to only *sort of* work. Here is what the segment looks like on disk:

```
00001800  e9 00 00 00 00 55 89 e5  83 ec 08 83 ec 0c 6a 68  |.....U........jh|
00001810  e8 31 02 00 00 83 c4 10  83 ec 0c 6a 65 e8 24 02  |.1.........je.$.|
00001820  00 00 83 c4 10 83 ec 0c  6a 6c e8 17 02 00 00 83  |........jl......|
00001830  c4 10 83 ec 0c 6a 6c e8  0a 02 00 00 83 c4 10 83  |.....jl.........|
00001840  ec 0c 6a 6f e8 fd 01 00  00 83 c4 10 83 ec 0c 6a  |..jo...........j|
00001850  0a e8 f0 01 00 00 83 c4  10 90 c9 c3 55 89 e5 83  |............U...|
00001860  ec 18 8b 45 08 66 89 45  f4 0f b7 45 f4 83 ec 0c  |...E.f.E...E....|
00001870  50 e8 fa 01 00 00 83 c4  10 c9 c3 55 89 e5 83 ec  |P..........U....|
00001880  18 8b 45 08 8b 55 0c 66  89 45 f4 89 d0 88 45 f0  |..E..U.f.E....E.|
00001890  0f b6 55 f0 0f b7 45 f4  83 ec 08 52 50 e8 eb 01  |..U...E....RP...|
000018a0  00 00 83 c4 10 90 c9 c3  55 89 e5 83 ec 18 c7 45  |........U......E|
000018b0  f4 00 00 00 00 83 ec 08  6a 0e 68 d4 03 00 00 e8  |........j.h.....|
000018c0  b7 ff ff ff 83 c4 10 83  ec 0c 68 d5 03 00 00 e8  |..........h.....|
000018d0  88 ff ff ff 83 c4 10 0f  b6 c0 c1 e0 08 89 45 f4  |..............E.|
000018e0  83 ec 08 6a 0f 68 d4 03  00 00 e8 8c ff ff ff 83  |...j.h..........|
000018f0  c4 10 83 ec 0c 68 d5 03  00 00 e8 5d ff ff ff 83  |.....h.....]....|
00001900  c4 10 0f b6 c0 09 45 f4  8b 45 08 c7 00 00 80 0b  |......E..E......|
00001910  00 8b 45 f4 89 c2 8b 45  08 66 89 50 04 90 c9 c3  |..E....E.f.P....|
00001920  55 89 e5 53 83 ec 14 8b  45 0c 88 45 f7 c6 45 f6  |U..S....E..E..E.|
00001930  f0 0f b6 45 f6 c1 e0 08  89 c2 0f b6 45 f7 09 d0  |...E........E...|
00001940  66 89 45 f4 0f b6 45 f7  83 f8 0a 75 11 8b 45 08  |f.E...E....u..E.|
00001950  0f b7 40 04 8d 50 50 8b  45 08 66 89 50 04 8b 45  |..@..PP.E.f.P..E|
00001960  08 8b 18 8b 45 08 0f b7  40 04 8d 48 01 8b 55 08  |....E...@..H..U.|
00001970  66 89 4a 04 0f b7 c0 01  c0 8d 14 03 0f b7 45 f4  |f.J...........E.|
00001980  66 89 02 90 8b 45 08 0f  b7 50 04 0f b7 c2 69 c0  |f....E...P....i.|
00001990  cd cc 00 00 c1 e8 10 66  c1 e8 06 66 89 45 f2 0f  |.......f...f.E..|
000019a0  b7 4d f2 89 c8 c1 e0 02  01 c8 c1 e0 04 29 c2 66  |.M...........).f|
000019b0  89 55 f2 8b 45 08 0f b7  40 04 0f b7 c0 69 c0 cd  |.U..E...@....i..|
000019c0  cc 00 00 c1 e8 10 66 c1  e8 06 66 89 45 f0 0f b7  |......f...f.E...|
000019d0  55 f0 89 d0 c1 e0 02 01  d0 c1 e0 04 89 c2 0f b7  |U...............|
000019e0  45 f2 01 d0 66 89 45 ee  83 ec 08 6a 0f 68 d4 03  |E...f.E....j.h..|
000019f0  00 00 e8 84 fe ff ff 83  c4 10 0f b7 45 ee 0f b6  |............E...|
00001a00  c0 83 ec 08 50 68 d4 03  00 00 e8 6c fe ff ff 83  |....Ph.....l....|
00001a10  c4 10 83 ec 08 6a 0e 68  d4 03 00 00 e8 5a fe ff  |.....j.h.....Z..|
00001a20  ff 83 c4 10 0f b7 45 ee  66 c1 e8 08 0f b6 c0 83  |......E.f.......|
00001a30  ec 08 50 68 d4 03 00 00  e8 3e fe ff ff 83 c4 10  |..Ph.....>......|
00001a40  90 8b 5d fc c9 c3 55 89  e5 83 ec 18 83 ec 0c 8d  |..]...U.........|
00001a50  45 f0 50 e8 50 fe ff ff  83 c4 10 83 ec 08 ff 75  |E.P.P..........u|
00001a60  08 8d 45 f0 50 e8 b6 fe  ff ff 83 c4 10 90 c9 c3  |..E.P...........|
00001a70  55 89 e5 83 ec 14 8b 45  08 66 89 45 ec 0f b7 45  |U......E.f.E...E|
00001a80  ec 89 c2 ec 88 45 ff 0f  b6 45 ff c9 c3 55 89 e5  |.....E...E...U..|
00001a90  83 ec 08 8b 45 08 8b 55  0c 66 89 45 fc 89 d0 88  |....E..U.f.E....|
00001aa0  45 f8 0f b6 45 f8 0f b7  55 fc ee 90 c9 c3 3a 00  |E...E...U.....:.|
00001ab0  00 00 03 00 27 00 00 00  01 01 fb 0e 0d 00 01 01  |....'...........|
```

And here is what is actually loaded into memory:

```
00000000  e9 00 00 00 00 55 89 e5  83 ec 08 83 ec 0c 6a 68  |.....U........jh|
00000010  e8 31 02 00 00 83 c4 10  83 ec 0c 6a 65 e8 24 02  |.1.........je.$.|
00000020  00 00 83 c4 10 83 ec 0c  6a 6c e8 17 02 00 00 83  |........jl......|
00000030  c4 10 83 ec 0c 6a 6c e8  0a 02 00 00 83 c4 10 83  |.....jl.........|
00000040  ec 0c 6a 6f e8 fd 01 00  00 83 c4 10 83 ec 0c 6a  |..jo...........j|
00000050  0a e8 f0 01 00 00 83 c4  10 90 c9 c3 55 89 e5 83  |............U...|
00000060  ec 18 8b 45 08 66 89 45  f4 0f b7 45 f4 83 ec 0c  |...E.f.E...E....|
00000070  50 e8 fa 01 00 00 83 c4  10 c9 c3 55 89 e5 83 ec  |P..........U....|
00000080  c0 83 ec 08 50 68 d4 03  00 00 e8 6c fe ff ff 83  |....Ph.....l....|
00000090  c4 10 83 ec 08 6a 0e 68  d4 03 00 00 e8 5a fe ff  |.....j.h.....Z..|
000000a0  ff 83 c4 10 0f b7 45 ee  66 c1 e8 08 0f b6 c0 83  |......E.f.......|
000000b0  ec 08 50 68 d4 03 00 00  e8 3e fe ff ff 83 c4 10  |..Ph.....>......|
000000c0  90 8b 5d fc c9 c3 55 89  e5 83 ec 18 83 ec 0c 8d  |..]...U.........|
000000d0  45 f0 50 e8 50 fe ff ff  83 c4 10 83 ec 08 ff 75  |E.P.P..........u|
000000e0  08 8d 45 f0 50 e8 b6 fe  ff ff 83 c4 10 90 c9 c3  |..E.P...........|
000000f0  55 89 e5 83 ec 14 8b 45  08 66 89 45 ec 0f b7 45  |U......E.f.E...E|
00000100  ec 89 c2 ec 88 45 ff 0f  b6 45 ff c9 c3 55 89 e5  |.....E...E...U..|
00000110  83 ec 08 8b 45 08 8b 55  0c 66 89 45 fc 89 d0 88  |....E..U.f.E....|
00000120  45 f8 0f b6 45 f8 0f b7  55 fc ee 90 c9 c3 3a 00  |E...E...U.....:.|
00000130  00 00 03 00 27 00 00 00  01 01 fb 0e 0d 00 01 01  |....'...........|
```

It seems like a contiguous chunk in the middle is missing. What could be the reason for this?

EDIT: following some suggestions I have added a missing `volatile` in `in` an switched to 48 bit PIO, but the issue persists.

Comment: looks like you have 24bit lba driver. where you need 48

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин I though it was always possible to use 24bit lba, how can I figure out whether that's the case? Currently I'm only working with qemu, not on actual hardware.

Comment: may be it's possible then. you then need late 90's hard drive there. i think quemu should offer some models

Comment: if quemu will use generic ata controller fo' sho' it will be 48

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин That makes sense, I was thinking that 48 bit drivers would be "backwards compatible" but I guess that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин I just modified my code to use the 48 bit PIO protocol and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: so you need `#define ATA_READ_MUL48                  0x29`        https://github.com/DragonFlyBSD/DragonFlyBSD/blob/5a4a4dbaed373c7df0dbbd0638ce487111b28c4e/sys/dev/disk/nata/ata-all.c#L750         Where you're using `#define ATA_READ48                      0x24`

Comment: no, looks like `ATA_READ_MUL48` is for off limit data

Comment: also check out this https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15311

Comment: One issue is `  asm ("in %1,%0"
       : "=a" (data)
       : "d" (port));`  should be `volatile` as it involves access to an external source the compiler isn't aware of. You don't want the optimizer to optimize this away.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That's true, I have amended my code but that was seemingly not the root issue.

Comment: and strange thing is that df bsd doesn't have `ATA_PORT_DRIVE_HEAD = 0x1F6` at all. idk where you'd take this stuff from. what head has to do with lba ?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: 0x1f6 is the ATA drive/head register or not? Maybe not the best choice of constant name though, true.

Comment: it's not about name . they do not have 0x1F6 . so i doubt line with it does something.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: I implemented this based on [this link](https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode#Drive_.2F_Head_Register_.28I.2FO_base_.2B_6.29). And it seems to work now.

Comment: what i offer is to comment  it out.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I have made two pretty trivial errors: first the code for `ins` is incorrect, as Michael Petch pointed out it was missing a `volatile`. Also, `dest` should have type `T*`:

```
template<typename T>
void ins(uint16_t port, uint32_t dest, uint32_t count)
{
  static_assert(detail::is_uint_le32_t<T>());

  T *dest_ptr = reinterpret_cast<T *>(dest);

  asm volatile("rep ins%z2"
               : "+D" (dest_ptr), "+c" (count), "=m" (*dest_ptr)
               : "d" (port)
               : "memory");
}
```

Then, critically, the line `pa_dest += DISK_SECT_SIZE / 4` is wrong. This should be `pa_dest += DISK_SECT_SIZE` since `ins` reads a whole sector (128 double words) and not just a quarter of it.

Comment: Passing a pointer as a `uint32_t dest` makes little sense.  Use `uintptr_t` or `void*`, or even `T*`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Interchangeable using fixed width integers and pointers to represent adresses is pretty common in OS development afaik.

Comment: It seems pointless to hard-code a pointer size here, though, just making it harder to port to x86-64 for example.  This code wouldn't need to change for 64-bit mode if you used `void*` and `size_t`.  So part of my objection is that it's a standard name like `uint32_t` that you can't redefine to be a 64-bit type, even moreso than it being an integer type.  (Although since this function only derefs it, not splitting it into page : offset parts or anything, arguably the caller should be the one casting it to `T*` if it's not already a pointer.) For pointer-as-int, use `uintptr_t` or a custom type

Comment: e.g. this is just pure inconvenience for the caller in a case like `ins(PORT, (uint32_t)&struct.buf, size)`

Comment: @PeterCordes: x86_64 is a good point, I should change this.

Comment: @PeterCordes i doubt machine is in memory paging mode at this stage. `uint32_t` do best there

Comment: also it depends on how this kernel is compiled. you'll use 64-bit pc for build but you need 32-bit result . And all this stuff